# Protractor on JSF

Tags: protractor

I need to click on a oneselectmenu and select an item made of primefaces JSF using protractor js.

Heres my code:

```
  it ('should pesquisa', function () {
    browser.get('localhost:8080/myapp/geral.xhtml');    

    var agruparPorFocus = element(protractor.By.xpath('//div[@id="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_panel"]/div/ul/li[4]')).click();
    var agruparPorInput = element(protractor.By.id('form-pesquisa:consultarPor_input'));

   });
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'Lilian-fx', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'Lilian-fx', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Array.forEach (native)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/lilian-fx/workspace/protractor/fwLite/spec.fwl.js:60:115)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/lilian-fx/workspace/protractor/fwLite/spec.fwl.js:49:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lilian-fx/workspace/protractor/fwLite/spec.fwl.js:5:1)

Finished in 17.565 seconds
5 tests, 4 assertions, 1 failure
```

that is the HTML code

```
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input id="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_focus" name="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_focus"
    autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <select id="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_input" name="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_input"
    tabindex="-1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'form-pesquisa:consultarPor',e:'change',p:'form-pesquisa:consultarPor'});">
        <option value="1">
            Meia Hora
        </option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">
            Dia
        </option>
        <option value="3">
            Mês
        </option>
        <option value="4">
            Ano
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<label style="width: 335px;" id="form-pesquisa:consultarPor_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">
    Dia
</label>
<div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c">
    </span>
</div>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
data-label="Meia Hora">
    Meia Hora
</li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight"
data-label="Dia">
    Dia
</li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
data-label="Mês">
    Mês
</li>o
</li>o
</li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all"
data-label="Ano">
    Ano
</li>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of issue log itself tells you what is happening.

```
ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

means that the protractor cannot find this element to interact with. This may be because the element may be visible on the browser after some time ( may be due to some AJAX call).

What I would suggest you is to have a kind of wait implemented so that you can wait for a specific period of time, until the element is visible and then access it.

I have never use Protractor, but a quick search tells me that you can use the [ExpectedConditions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/9bc1c53e40161521b0c125a810f86235c974f100) to achieve this.

Here is a good [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor) which tells you how you can implement a custom wait (called Explicit Wait) using the ExpectedConditions.